# Base 64 Decoding in android issues

Tags: android, encoding, base64, decoding, utf8-decode

I have received the decode `String` from a server by using this encoding process var

```
 data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (text); 
 text =  System.Convert.ToBase64String (data);
```

on my android app we using

```
byte [] data = Base64.decode(base64data,Base64.DEFAULT);
String text1 = new String (data, "UTF-8");
```

but when we set this setting to text view it does not show formatted.

Thank you....

Comment: @ Ironman please check question code

Answer (score 0):

Use it before set text .

```
text1 = text1.replaceAll("[\n\r]", "WRAP");
text1 = text1.replaceAll("WRAP", "\n\r");
```